# How to enable hibernation in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu

In Linux Ubuntu 12.04, hibernation has been disabled by default in policykit.
How can I enable this back?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04